# How to store sums into MS Access table?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I know how it sounds, you shouldn't store calculated fields into an Access table. However, this is my case:

I have a form where a user inputs bale weights. At the bottom of the form are two fields that calculate the total weights of all the bales, and the total number of bales. These two fields need to be stored into our table so we can keep track of the totals from shift to shift.

I have the two calculated fields, and then I have two hidden fields that have control sources for the table. The two hidden fields are in the parent form of this bale weight subform. There is an OnClick event on the control when you enter a new bale weight that updates the parent hidden controls with the form's calculated controls.

The problem:
These fields are not updated immediately after entering a new bale weight, and if I put requery, recalc, refresh into the afterupdate event the cursor goes to the first record which is very user-UNfriendly.
Sometimes someone has to delete or change a bunch of records in the middle of this form. every click and update bringing you to the top (or to the bottom if I add DoCmd.GoToRecord,,AC NewRecord).

TLDR:
I need a way to get the sum of all the bales from a 12 hour shift to store into our table that doesn't involve refreshing, because that messes up the placement of the cursor if the records need to be updated.

I tried updating the table after the bale weight form loses focus, but this isn't consistent with updating both total bale weight and total bale count hidden controls immediately.

Comment: Requery the form's Recordset, not the form, and record focus will not change: `Me.Recordset.Requery`. Or don't update the sum fields until ready to commit record. Use form BeforeUpdate event. These sums should be calculable 'by shift' when needed.

Comment: Why would you use OnClick instead of AfterUpdate event of data controls?

Comment: Edit question to show code that saves the sums to parent record fields.

Comment: Me.recordset.requery worked perfectly, thank you! I just had a minor problem when switching from the sub form to the main form, it gave me a "this has been edited by another user" message, which I got rid of by using the same code in the OnExit event of the sub form. Also, I made a mistake about the OnClick event, it was an OnEnter Event. But I did add the code to OnEnter as well as Afterupdate to account for switching from main form back to bale weights. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SetFocus command on your expression.
Then the cursor will go to that field.

```
Me.controlfield.Setfocus
```

Or

```
Me.controlfield.Text.Setfocus
```